# Module is not available! But I've declared and included it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm programming a web app in Angular.
I've created a module that will manage the Accounting.
I'm using Bower and Gulp to compile the javascript.

hostels/hostels.module.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.hostels', [
            'app.hostels.authentication',
            'app.hostels.rooms',
            'app.hostels.guests',
            'app.hostels.providers',
            'app.hostels.products',
            'app.hostels.employees',
            'app.hostels.accounting'
        ]);
})();
```

hostels/accounting/accounting.module.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.hostels.accounting', [

        ]);
})();
```

hostels/accounting/list/list.controller.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.hostels.accounting')
        .controller('ListAccountingController', ListController);

    /* @ngInject */
    function ListController ($scope, $http, $location, APP, ApiResourceBalance, $log ) {
        var vm = this;
        $log.log('Balance!!!');

    }

})();
```

The issue is that, when I run the app I get an error message in console sayin' that app.hostels.accounting module is not defined (In list.controller.js).

It's a clone of other modules I've made, just changed names and can't find where the error is.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems obvious, but did you make sure the file is included on the page?

Comment: Does your HTML include all the JS files? You may have accidentally excluded it.

Comment: yes, and make sure the sequence is correct

Comment: There's a script that includes all that's on the app's directory. That's not the issue

Comment: make sure you inculde `accounting.module.js` before  `list.controller.js` on your html file

Comment: It's compiled with gulp & bower. I'm not including file by file

Comment: you have to use *.module.js first, then the rest in gulp.src glob. gulp does not do anything special for order of files but angular do care about that

Comment: Gulp is including the module declaration after the controllers. Maybe that has something to do with it

Answer (score 0):

I think,gulp not include your new module into your project,maybe you set wrong regular expression.my configuration in below:

```
js: {
    main: 'app/main.js',
    src: [
        // application config
        'app.config.js',

        // application bootstrap file
        'app/main.js',

        // main module
        'app/app.js',

        // module files
        'app/**/module.js',

        // other js files [controllers, services, etc.]
        'app/**/!(module)*.js'
    ],
    tpl: 'app/**/*.html' 
}
```

Comment: It's including all files. The controllers are included a few lines before the module declaration. Maybe that has something to do